# jquery $.totalStorage - Remove all keys

Tags: jquery, local-storage

I would like to clear out all items from storage. I looked at the jquery $.totalStorage js, I don't see a function to remove all keys and objects.

Is there an easy way to do this without having to look through all items and calling 'deleteItem()'?

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add this functionality to the [totalStorage](https://github.com/jarednova/jquery-total-storage/blob/master/jquery.total-storage.js) plugin.

Add this public method to the plugin

```
$.totalStorage.removeAll = function(){
    return $.totalStorage.impl.removeAll();
};
```

Then inside the `$.totalStorage.impl` object literal put this function -

```
removeAll: function(){
    if (!supported){
        try {
            var pairs = document.cookie.split(";");
            for (var i = 0; i<pairs.length; i++){
                var pair = pairs[i].split('=');
                var key = pair[0];
                $.cookie(key, null);
            }
        } catch(e){
            return null;
        }
    } else {
        ls.clear();
    }
},
```

/edit

I forked the `totalStorage` plugin and added a `removeAll` method - [you can get it here on my GitHub](https://github.com/rossmartin/jquery-total-storage)

Now you can clear local storage by calling `$.totalStorage.removeAll();`

[Here is a jsFiddle using the `removeAll` method](http://jsfiddle.net/rossmartin/5KZLs/)

Comment: @user998066 Np you're welcome.  I think I'm gonna use this jQuery plugin in cases where I have to support localStorage on IE7.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps not directly with this library, but if you want to remove everything knowing `localStorage` exists you can do this:

```
localStorage.clear();
```

Answer (score 0):

[No](https://github.com/jarednova/jquery-total-storage/blob/master/jquery.total-storage.js#L131). You must remove items one by one.

Answer (score 0):

Using **jQuery** you can do with with ease

```
$.each($.totalStorage.getAll(),function(i,obj) {
    $.totalStorage.deleteItem(obj.key);
});
```